# Is there a way to copy an extension from a browser to another?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to copy an extension from a browser to another browser (both chromium based)?
In windows 10 I know the browser reads its data from this folder:
C:\Users<account_name\AppData\Local<browser>\User Data\Default
in Default there are several folders, among many:
"Extensions" and "Local Extension Settings"
which have as many folders inside as there are extensions installed and each of these folders has the extension id as its name.
So I tried copying Extensions\<id_ext> and "Local Extension Settings"\<id_ext> to their respective folders of another browser, but that wasn't enough.
Do I forget something (some other folder and\or registry key) or i's not possible to do this operation (without breaking the browser of course)?

**EDIT**
my goal is to have an old version of an extension fully installed in the browser (make the browser believe that it comes from the CWS) but in which I have disabled future updates (by modifying the update_url field in the manifest.json file with a fictitious address)

**EDIT # 2**
**I will try to add two lines to better explain my purposes.
I've read something on SO and beyond, but nothing that can enlighten me about it.
My aim is to install an old version of an extension created by me
(I have the extension public key but I no longer have the private key), to block the update for a certain time and then update when I want by resetting the update_url field in the manifest.**

Thanks

Comment: Did you search SO for solutions to your problem? Have you found any solutions, but for some reason, you don't want to use them? If so, please update your question with this information. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "my goal is to have an old version of an extension fully installed in the browser (make the browser believe that it comes from the CWS)" --- What do you mean by "make the browser believe that it comes from the CWS", and why is this important?